# Can I link to a SharePoint document using the site name, folder, and name?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, hyperlink, path, sharing

I have a SharePoint folder of documents named uniformly. I was hoping there was an easy way to link to the document without having to share it/generate a link ID at first. I'd like to embed this in a report so users can quickly pull up a summary.

e.g. `https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/sales/Shared Documents/Forms/myfilename.doc`

Is this possible? If I try, it assumes `myfilename.doc` is a folder.

Comment: I don't think I was able to catch your requirement. If you only need to have an easy way to get the link to a particular document, you can click the document's setting-menu to open by clicking the ellipsis (`...`) which includes a the document's URL.

Comment: Thanks Moe.  All the files are uploaded tot he library and named customernumber.pdf (e.g. 12345.pdf)  My report comes out in Excel and I just want to be able to form a URL link to the file using a pattern.  I don't want to have to retrieve a custom link for every document if I already know the path and name.  If it was a normal web server i could just go to the path & filename provided the directory was shared.  If the document wasn't there the link would just be broken...  I was hoping that this simple functionality (or something akin to it,) is available in SharePoint.

Comment: The link to each document should be e.g. `https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/sales/Shared Documents/myfilename.doc`, which differs from the one in your question by excluding the `/Forms`. The pattern is static and you only need to change the filename.

Comment: Thanks Moe!  This worked perfectly, but was not very easy to find online.  Also important to note that if you use sub folders these have to be pathed with extended characters: (e.g. /Shared%20Documents%2FSub%20Folder%20Name%20/filename.doc )

Answer (score 0):

The link to each document should be e.g. https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/sales/Shared Documents/myfilename.doc, which differs from the one in your question by excluding the /Forms. The pattern is static and you only need to change the filename.

Also important to note that if you use sub folders these have to be pathed with extended characters after the site name: (e.g. /Shared%20Documents%2FSub%20Folder%20Name%20/filename.doc )