# Build a document link from path and file name in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document, url, hyperlink, path

I am re wording this question to be more specific:

Using the site, path, and file name how do you build a link to a document, programmatically or using an excel formula.

In previous versions you simply built a link like the example below and its would allow a user to link to that document.

Site = constant (https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite)

Path = variable (Document Library/subfolder/subfolder)

file = variable (filename.*)

eg.
https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite/Controlled_Doc/Subfolder/attachments/Photo1.jpg

Been going in circles on the forums and can't find a reference to what the character substitutions should be for sub-folders if that is the source of the problem. This is very similar to the question asked [Can I link to a SharePoint document using the site name, folder, and name?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218644/can-i-link-to-a-sharepoint-document-using-the-site-name-folder-and-name/218651#218651)
how ever this is specific to the modern pages in SharePoint Online.
If the problem is just in the formating of the link as specified for sub folders what is the reference for the character substitution?

For context this will be going in a cell within a spreadsheet that is already populated with a large volume of data.

Not interested in the GUI features within SharePoint like export to excel or the option to copy link by pressing a button. I would like to avoid coding if possible and building an API call.

Comment: Do you want to get the clean URL of documents inside subfolders in document library??

Comment: basically don't care too much about the link structure so long as it works. going into a spreadsheet for very low tech users.

Comment: So What do you want exactly? Do you want to export the url for all documents in Excel file or just the clean url for some particular document?

Comment: the ability to link to a document in a sharepoint online environment using the path and filename as the input to build the link.

Comment: I don't know your all requirements but you can use **Export to Excel** option in SharePoint online which will give you the link to the documents easily.

Comment: The link cell in the output spreadsheet as you suggest is what i am wanting to build from the path and filename parameters. i have clarified the question

Comment: I don't know about the part where you want to create link in excel. But, you can create link to the document if you know the site url, document library, subfolder and document file name like `siteUrl/documentLibrary/Folder/SubFolder/FileName.extension`. It will give you the correct document URL.

Answer (score 0):

The path and filename escaping in SharePoint isn't anything unique.  You can make sure your path is handling special characters by passing the text through the ENCODEURL function in Excel.  This will automatically replace spaces with %20 for example.

Comment: This fixes the encoding but the links are still not working